# Floating-point error mess

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding-error

I have been trying to figure this floating-point problem out in javascript.
This is an example of what I want to do:

```
var x1 = 0
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    x1+= 0.2    
}
```

However in this form I will get a rounding error, 0.2 -> 0.4 -> 0.600...001 doing that.

I have tried `parseFloat`, `toFixed` and `Math.round` suggested in other threads but none of it have worked for me. So are there anyone who could make this work, because I feel that I have run out of options.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I think it would help if you posted what attempts you made and why they were unsatisfactory, so we get a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: When you use floating-point, you must accept that there are rounding errors in the arithmetic, and you must design your code to work with that. Because the value .6 is not exactly representable in binary floating-point, no code whatsoever will result in a binary floating-point object having exactly the value .6. You must accept that there will be errors. You have not stated what problem these values are causing you.

Comment: Tibos: Yea I probably should have (First time doing this) I might have been to obsessed trying to figure out how to get exactly 0.6.

Eric: Thank you, accepting that I can't get 0.6 helped me change my code and figure the real problem. Which was that the x1 value was used in accessing an array value, and in a % == 0, causing my if statements to not run.

So thank you, I am new to the world of coding and stackoverflow, so I am sorry if I am a bit of a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost always ignore the floating point "errors" while you're performing calculations - they won't make any difference to the end result unless you really care about the 17th significant digit or so.

You normally only need to worry about rounding when you *display* those values, for which `.toFixed(1)` would do perfectly well.

Whatever happens you simply cannot coerce the number 0.6 into exactly that value.  The closest IEEE 754 double precision is exactly 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, which when displayed within typical precision limits in JS is displayed as 0.5999999999999999778

Indeed JS can't even tell that 0.5999999999999999778 !== (e.g) 0.5999999999999999300 since their binary representation is the same.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your edit is inappropriate.  The value I gave is the nearest one possible with a Javascript Number  (IEEE 754 double precision).

Comment: Thanks, I think I was to obsessed trying to get exactly 0.6, accepting that made me change the code to allow that.

Comment: @Alnitak: No, that value is not the nearest one possible. That value may be displayed when you show that number of digits, but it is not the actual value. That should be obvious, since it is binary floating-point, and every binary floating-point fraction ends in 5 as the last significant digit. (.5, .25, .125, .0625,…). The value I entered is the actual value represented, as specified by IEEE 754. It is exactly 5404319552844595 / 9007199254740992. (The denominator is 2**53.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil that may be the _exact_ decimal representation of the IEEE 754 mantissa corresponding to 0.6, but JS simply cannot supply represent numbers with that amount of precision so the additional digits are IMHO irrelevant.  Try, e.g. `0.5999999999999999778 === 0.6` - as far as JS is concerned they're the same number.

Comment: @Alnitak: It is not a matter of opinion. The standard for JavaScript, ECMA-262, specifies that IEEE 754 is used. IEEE 754 specifies that, for a binary format, the value represented is +1 or -1 multiplied by a power of two multiplied by an integer. See clauses 3.3 and 3.4 for details. It is a precise mathematical definition of the exact number represented. JavaScript **does** represent these numbers; that is what the value it uses for `.6` **is**. It does arithmetic based on these values in IEEE 754 (e.g., roundings occur based on the IEEE-754 values, not the limited number of digits you show).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see from your profile that you do have expertise in this area but I also think you're being over pedantic on this. Hell, I did my first work on floating point representation myself over 25 years ago, converting PDP-11 format floats into something an 8087 could handle.  If the extra digits were useful then `.toFixed()` would allow more than 20 decimal places, but it doesn't, because that extra precision is potentially misleading.

Comment: @Alnitak: The reasoning that if extra digits are useful then `toFixed` would support them is specious. ECMA-262 explicitly allows an implementation to extend support beyond 20 digits, thus implicitly recognizing they may be useful. The reason some implementations do not is that it is hard work. Converting correctly is not easy. And the exact values are important: In order to reason about the properties of calculations, and to write proofs that code is correct, the value represented must be known correctly.

Comment: In any case, you are clearly wrong on your assertion that my edit was inappropriate. It is quite clear, formally specified and not a matter of opinion, that the value represented is exactly the value I supplied and is not the value you have.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand how the rounding errors are accumulating, and get more insight on what is happenning at lower level, here is a small explanantion:
I will assume that IEEE 754 double precision standard is used by underlying software/hardware, with default rounding mode (round to nearest even).

1/5 could be written in base 2 with a pattern repeating infinitely

```
  0.00110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...
```

But in floating point, the significand - starting at most significant 1 bit - has to be rounded to a finite number of bits (53)

So there is a small rounding error when representing 0.2 in binary:

```
  0.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

Back to decimal representation, this rounding error corresponds to a small excess 0.000000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125 above 1/5

The first operation is then exact because 0.2+0.2 is like 2*0.2 and thus does not introduce any additional error, it's like shifting the fraction point:

```
  0.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
+ 0.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  0.0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100
```

But of course, the excess above 2/5 is doubled 0.00000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

The third operation 0.2+0.2+0.2 will result in this binary number

```
  0.011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
+ 0.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  0.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001110
```

But unfortunately, it requires 54 bits of significand (the span between leading 1 and trailing 1), so another rounding error is necessary to represent the result as a double:

```
  0.10011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100
```

Notice that the number was rounded upper, because by default floats are rounded to nearest even in case of perfect tie. We already had an error by excess, so bad luck, successive errors did cumulate rather than annihilate...

So the excess above 3/5 is now 0.000000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

You could reduce a bit this accumulation of errors by using

```
x1 = i / 5.0
```

Since 5 is represented exactly in float (101.0 in binary, 3 significand bits are enough), and since that will also be the case of i (up to 2^53), there is a single rounding error when performing the division, and IEEE 754  then guarantees that you get the nearest possible representation.

For example 3/5.0 is represented as:

```
  0.10011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

Back to decimal, the value is represented by default 0.00000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625 under 3/5

Note that both errors are very tiny, but in second case 3/5.0, four times smaller in magnitude than 0.2+0.2+0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to do fixed-point arithmetic instead of floating point.  For example, if you are doing financial calculations in dollars with amounts that are always multiples of $0.01, you can switch to using cents internally, and then convert to (and from) dollars only when displaying values to the user (or reading input from the user).  For more complicated scenarios, you can use a fixed-point arithmetic library.