# Generating an array of floats produces a weird result

Tags: ruby, arrays, floating-point, enumerable

I want to generate an array of float. For instance, this one:

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
```

So, I use this tiny line:

```
(0.5..2).step(0.1).to_a
```

But it produces this instead:

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2000000000000002, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7000000000000002, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2.0]
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You've done nothing wrong.  The `1.1` you got isn't actually 1.1 either.

Comment: Arithmetic loops on floating point is a very common question whatever the language... For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735083/floating-point-error-mess/21737478#21737478 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356970/calculating-the-function-and-checking-its-domain/24374791#24374791 and surely many others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Rational Literals, Then Map to Floats

Floating point numbers can bite you. Specifically, [binary can't represent 0.1 accurately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Ruby has a number of classes for dealing accurately with arbitrary-precision numbers, including [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) and [Rational](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Rational.html).

You can use the new [2.1 syntax for rational literals](http://ruby.about.com/od/Whats-New-in-Ruby-210/fl/Whats-new-in-Ruby-210-Numerics.htm) to create your series of floats. For example:

```
(0.5r..2r).step(0.1r).map &:to_f
#=> [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
```

Doing it this way may look a little more cluttered than the [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26237871/1301972), but this approach is applicable to a wider range of precision problems where dividing by 10.0 is not the solution.

Comment: Well, this way is much more beautiful, I accept it instead, for the future viewers of this question, but it requires ruby > 2.1 indeed

Answer (score 6):

Floating point numbers like `0.1` can not be represented precisely. Using floating pointer numbers as step would give you unexpected result like that.

A better alternative is:

```
(5 .. 20).map {|e| e / 10.0}
#=> [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
```

Comment: You don't need the to_a.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as @YuHao suggests--clean and easy-to-read--but I would like to point out that you could also use the [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

v = BigDecimal.new(0.5, 1)
a = (20-5+1).times.with_object([]) { |_,arr| arr << v.to_f; v += 0.1 }
  #=> [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2,
  #    1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
```

Notes:

- When initializing a `BigDecimal` object with a `Float`, the precision must be given (here that is `, 1`).
- If `v` is an instance of `BigDecimal`, so is `v + 0.1`.
- `BigDecimal` has no `succ` method, so iteration is not possible. Hence, one cannot just map a `BigDecimal` range into an array of `Floats`. (Ranges of `BD`'s are permitted, though I question the utility of a range that can't be iterated.)

Answer (score 0):

An additional problem,how to get this result（Retained 2 decimal places）

[0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00]

Comment: Do not worry for that.
    irb(main):001:0> 5.0 == 5
    => true